# freeradius azure ad domain services ldaps

Tags: freeradius

I am trying to configure freeradius to authenticate using Azure AD Domain services with ldaps.
I can connect to addds and an ldapwhoami successfully authenticates a user.

Radtest with the same user gives me:

```
Received Access-Reject Id 40 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:45303 length 20
(0) -: Expected Access-Accept got Access-Reject
```

And freeradius says:

```
(1)     [ldap] = notfound
(1)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password) {
(1)     if ((ok || updated) && User-Password)  -> FALSE
(1)     [expiration] = noop
(1)     [logintime] = noop
(1) pap: WARNING: No "known good" password found for the user.  Not setting Auth-Type
(1) pap: WARNING: Authentication will fail unless a "known good" password is available
(1)     [pap] = noop
(1)   } # authorize = ok
(1) ERROR: No Auth-Type found: rejecting the user via Post-Auth-Type = Reject
(1) Failed to authenticate the user
```

I followed this post...
[here](https://www.nasirhafeez.com/freeradius-with-ldaps-on-azure-ad-domain-services/)

I know this is not the most sensible way to do this but grateful if anyone can tell me what I am missing?